# How to traverse up "nodes"?

Tags: java, nodes

I can't seem to find the correct search terms (as I'm sure this question has been asked before), so I"ll ask again.

How do I write the code for going up a node's "previous" until there are no more?
Note: I'm not allowed to use helper methods (so I don't think I can use recursive methods).

Essentially I want to print out a node's "previous" (which points to a previous node) until I run out.

Example (in pseudocode):

```
    node.prev
    node.prev.prev
    node.prev.prev.prev
```

**Edit:**
I'm not actually dealing with nodes, this is more accurate.
So I have Actors, with a "label" that points to the previous actor. I'm trying to write a loop for something like this:

```
   a = g.label(actor);
   b = g.label(a);
   c = g.label(b);
```

When I write the code as:

```
   while(g.label(a) != null) {
   a = g.label(a);
   }
```

I get stuck on the very first actor.

Comment: You'll need to include a snippet that shows what the node class looks like.  Generically, you might want a loop that does something like `while (node.getPrev() != null) { node = node.getPrev(); }`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question looks like homework to me. While asking homework questions is perfectly fine, there are some good guidelines for asking homework questions here: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/238586). Summarized, they are: make an attempt to solve the problem yourself first; ask about specific problems with your existing code; let us know that the question is homework; make sure your class allows using Q&A for help; don't copy and paste an answer's code without first understanding what it does and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to traverse the tree from bottom up?

There's no way good way to do this if each node only refrences the child node. If each node references child and parent (or just parent in this case), it should be pretty easy.

```
Node currentNode = new MyNode();
while (currentNode.parent != null) {
    currentNode = currentNode.parent;
}
// currentNode should now be the topmost node in the tree
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bit of a misunderstanding on what the `actors()` method should be doing.  Or, should be referred to as.

Let's assume, from what you've described, that your class is this:

```
public class Actor {
    private Actor label;
    // other fields

    // other setters and getters
    public Actor getLabel() {
        return label;
    }
}
```

I've taken the liberty to add the `getLabel()` method with no arguments, as it is a simple getter.

With that said, let's take your loop (modified with the above) into account:

```
while(g.getLabel() != null) {
    a = g.getLabel();
}
```

The effect on this should be apparent:  **you're never updating your `g` reference.**  Hence, you will have an infinite loop.

Suppose instead, you decided to start with a *known* value - something that may or may not be `null`, and if it wasn't, you wanted to continue walking towards the previous label.

If that's the case, then you only really need one variable to hold the current position, and another variable as the marker reference.  Let's assume that `a` will hold the current position, and `g` will be the marker reference.

```
Actor a = g.getLabel();
while(a != null) {
    a = a.getLabel();
}
```

This will update the reference in `a` until it points to the last non-null instance of `Actor` in your hierarchy.

Comment: For some reason the "while" part doesn't work. If I replace the "while(a != null)" with "for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)" it works as it should, the only problem with using a for loop is in case I don't know how many previous actors there were. I'm not sure why the for loop works, but the while loop gets stuck on the first actor?

Comment: I don't know enough about your case.  I only provided this as an example.  I would believe, if `getLabel` behaved in the manner I described it should, then there wouldn't be an issue.  The `for` loop makes absolutely no sense to me.